Why are latches inferred in my FSM design despite driving all signals in every state?
I'm working on a FSM design in Verilog and getting inferred latches during synthesis in Synopsys Design Vision. Below is the Verilog code for my FSM:
// control path
  //control path
  always @(*) begin
    casex (current_state)
      s0: begin
        read_addr_sel = 2'b10;
        size_count_sel = 2'b10;
        ABenable = 1'b0;
        A_times_B_enable = 1'b0;
        Accumulate_sel = 2'b10;
        finish = 1'b0;
        next_state = s0;
        if (go == 1'b1) next_state = s1;
      end
      s1: begin
        read_addr_sel = 2'b00;
        size_count_sel = 2'b10;
        ABenable = 1'b0;
        A_times_B_enable = 1'b0;
        Accumulate_sel = 2'b10;
        finish = 1'b0;
        next_state = s2;
      end
      s2: begin
        read_addr_sel = 2'b01;
        size_count_sel = 2'b10;
        ABenable = 1'b0;
        A_times_B_enable = 1'b0;
        Accumulate_sel = 2'b10;
        finish = 1'b0;
        next_state = s3;
      end
      s3: begin
        read_addr_sel = 2'b01;
        size_count_sel = 2'b00;
        ABenable = 1'b0;
        A_times_B_enable = 1'b0;
        Accumulate_sel = 2'b10;
        finish = 1'b0;
        next_state = s4;
      end
      s4: begin
        read_addr_sel = 2'b01;
        size_count_sel = 2'b01;
        ABenable = 1'b1;
        A_times_B_enable = 1'b0;
        Accumulate_sel = 2'b10;
        finish = 1'b0;
        next_state = s5;
      end
      s5: begin
        read_addr_sel = 2'b01;
        size_count_sel = 2'b01;
        ABenable = 1'b1;
        A_times_B_enable = 1'b1;
        Accumulate_sel = 2'b00;
        finish = 1'b0;
        next_state = s6;
      end
      s6: begin
        read_addr_sel = 2'b01;
        size_count_sel = 2'b01;
        ABenable = 1'b1;
        A_times_B_enable = 1'b1;
        Accumulate_sel = 2'b01;
        finish = 1'b0;
        next_state = s6;
        if (SizeCount == 16'b11) next_state = s7;
      end
      s7: begin
        read_addr_sel = 2'b10;
        size_count_sel = 2'b01;
        ABenable = 1'b1;
        A_times_B_enable = 1'b1;
        Accumulate_sel = 2'b01;
        finish = 1'b0;
        next_state = s7;
        if (SizeCount == 16'b01) next_state = s8;
      end
      s8: begin
        read_addr_sel = 2'b10;
        size_count_sel = 2'b10;
        ABenable = 1'b0;
        A_times_B_enable = 1'b1;
        Accumulate_sel = 2'b01;
        finish = 1'b0;
        next_state = s9;
      end
      s9: begin
        read_addr_sel = 2'b10;
        size_count_sel = 2'b10;
        ABenable = 1'b0;
        A_times_B_enable = 1'b0;
        Accumulate_sel = 2'b01;
        finish = 1'b0;
        next_state = s10;
      end
      s10: begin
        read_addr_sel = 2'b10;
        size_count_sel = 2'b10;
        ABenable = 1'b0;
        A_times_B_enable = 1'b0;
        Accumulate_sel = 2'b10;
        finish = 1'b1;
        next_state = s0;
      end
    endcase
  end


After running read_verilog in Design Vision, I get the following inferred memory devices warning:

From my understanding, I have driven every signal (finish, A_times_B_enable, etc.) in every state, so I don't understand why latches are being inferred.
Could someone explain why this might be happening and how to fix it?
I expected that since I assigned values to all the output signals in every state of the FSM, no latches would be created during synthesis. But, Design Vision is still detecting latches for signals like finish, A_times_B_enable, and others.

The report shows that next_state is a 4-bit signal.  I assume current_state is also a 4-bit signal.  This means that there are 16 possible decimal values for the current_state signal: 0-15.
The problem is that your case statement only accounts for 11 of the 16 states: s0 to s10.  There are 5 states unaccounted for.  Therefore, you are not making assignments for all possible states.  This is why you end up with unintended latches.
The synthesis tool is a piece of software that has a set of rules.  When it encounters specific patterns in the Verilog code that it parses, it tries to map the input code to known hardware components, like flip flops and latches.  It doesn't really know that you designed an FSM; all it sees is a case statement where you have only accounted for 11 of the 16 possible states.  To the synthesis tool, it is irrelevant whether or not you can reach these states via simulation or in a fabricated ASIC.
A common way to avoid the latches is to add a default to the case statement, setting all the signals to benign values.  For example, I arbitrarily chose some values, but you need to review them to see if they are appropriate for your design:
  s10: begin
    read_addr_sel = 2'b10;
    size_count_sel = 2'b10;
    ABenable = 1'b0;
    A_times_B_enable = 1'b0;
    Accumulate_sel = 2'b10;
    finish = 1'b1;
    next_state = s0;
  end
  default: begin
    read_addr_sel = 2'b00;
    size_count_sel = 2'b00;
    ABenable = 1'b0;
    A_times_B_enable = 1'b0;
    Accumulate_sel = 2'b00;
    finish = 1'b0;
    next_state = s0;
  end
endcase


It is unusual to use a casex statement for an FSM; consider using case instead.

Thanks, adding a default case helped, and I understand it is a good practice to do so. My confusion is that I designed the FSM for every possible situation I could think of, and I assumed that the FSM would only cycle through states S0 to S10, never entering S11 to S15, and thus never latching.
After adding the default case, I was able to synthesize my design. However, I’m still unsure how states S11 and beyond are reachable in the design.
